# Could Neo's supernatural powers in the real world suggest that there were a super-matrix?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix-reloaded, the-matrix-revolutions

That was what I thought when they released The Matrix Reloaded, and later in The Matrix Revolutions, when Neo exhibits super-natural powers in the "real" world.
Giving the posibility that the "real" world could be just another simulated reality.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Thinking is what can produce great answers.  Now if the argument turns into crap about how The Matrix is a comment on how AMD is better than Intel because of Neo battling Smith...THAT is too much thinking.  This is a great contrast to the recent debates of the Source being wireless in nature.

Comment: There is support for this theory. http://www.cracked.com/article/18367_6-insane-fan-theories-that-actually-make-great-movies-better/

Comment: With the edit, I'm not clear on where this **question** is going....

Comment: @TylerShads I think the answer is that it was suggested a supermatrix, because it's more likely within the matrix's universe, considering the machine's cold logic, but the idea was possible abandoned.

Comment: But my point is that you're making it less and less like a **question** and more and more like a **rant**.  The difference is one gets closed and the other does not.  [It is ok to ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) but not in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is that it was suggested a supermatrix, because it's more likely within the matrix's universe, considering the machine's cold logic, but the idea was possible abandoned.

**Why a super-matrix?**

The machines where able to defeat Neo and Agent Smith, and his viral propagation, at the same time, and took Zion after the battle.

If the machines' ultimate goal was to end the conspiracy. Why they didn't exterminate every free human being. If the reason was that machines were "man" of his word, I pass thanks.

But, if there were a super-matrix, they could allow the free humans to continue living, just because they were more useful conected to the super-matrix.

**Was the super-matrix idea abandoned?**

After so many years, I think so. Maybe they couldn't explain in a credible way how the free humans would know when they definitely defeated the machines... if there could be a super-matrix, why not many nested matrix layers each with a diferent simulated reality even more "real" that the previous one.

Answer (score 9):

No, a pretty much official explanation exists. And the question is not really "open". As I've stated in [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8370/why-did-neo-have-powers-in-the-real-world/8395#8395), it's explained by the fact that when Neo comes into contact with the Source (i.e. when he meets the Architect), his brain becomes a wireless connection.

After all, the real time in the Matrix franchise is set in a tech-wise advanced future, so why shouldn't a much more powerful wireless connection exist? I think the term wireless here is used to explain the concept of the "without wires" kind of technology, and not necessarily the actual wireless connection we all currently know.

The fact that Neo can, for example, affect the Sentinels with viruses wirelessly is not that absurd in a Sci-fi franchise like the Matrix.

Comment: There are other theories floating about that states that his body may have different plugs in them that allow for this signal as well.

Comment: @TylerShads Yes, while it's said that his brain became a wireless connection, it wouldn't be that absurd to think that all of the plugs in Neo's body would be capable of being wireless as well. :)

Comment: It seems odd that they didn't even try to detect a wireless connection when Neo got trapped in the simulation without any physical connection. I've updated my question to add a personal observation regarding the logic on a super-matrix.

Comment: @rraallvv What simulation are you referring to?

Comment: @Alenanno They mentioned that the subway where Neo encounters for the first time the Trainman, is not the matrix, but another place between the real world and the matrix. Therefore a simulated reality too.

Answer (score 1):

It could.

The idea of a "dream within a dream" was probably popularized by the [Edgar Allan Poe poem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_within_a_dream), published in 1849, and so the idea has had time to pervade the public meme space.

Comment: Yes... maybe the Wachowski duo tried a similar approach in the matrix, I think they abandoned that idea but leave the option open on purpose... maybe they couldn't explain in a credible way how the free humans would know when they definitely defeated the machines... if there could be a super-matrix, why not many nested matrix layers

Comment: This seems more like a comment rather than an explanation as to why this may be the case.

Comment: Does it really need a complicated explanation? The concept has been around for *at least* 163 years, as clearly established by a credible reference. What more do you need?

Comment: The trope itself needs no explanation, I'm thinking more of a Matrix-Universe explanation as to why this could be a possibility in the story itself.

Comment: I'll work on that - let me think about how to word it.